# Prove it is hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I got stuck on the following problem:

Let $X$ be a $T_4$ space and $A \subset X$ be a closed subspace. I want to show, that quotient space $X /A$ obtained from $X$ by crushing $A$ down to a point is hausdorff.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: Use the fact that if $x\in X\setminus A$, the normality of $X$ ensures that there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $A\subseteq V$; these will give you disjoint open nbhds in $X/A$ of the points corresponding to $x$ and $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ is closed.  Hence so is $q×q:X×X\to X/A×X/A$.  Hence the diagonal is closed in $X/A×X/A$, as it equals $\{(q×q)(\Delta)\}$, the image of a closed set.

Comment: How do you define now a product? I don't get that step

Comment: The product topology.  Open sets are products of open sets.

Comment: Here, perhaps I should mention, I'm using the equivalency that a space is hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed.

Comment: Just as the quotient topology is the finest that makes the quotient map continuous, the product topology is the coarsest that makes the projections continuous.

Comment: Okay thank you, I gonna try this out